# alter tablespace db2 when the Table space type is "AUTOMATIC STORAGE"

Tags: database, db2, tablespace, automatic-storage, ibm-db2

Good day,

I would like to alter a `tablespace` to bigger size. The following is my query:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE USERSPACE1
     resize (ALL 8192)
```

Then I hit error as follow:

```
[Error Code: -20318, SQL State: 42858]  The ALTER TABLESPACE statement failed because the change is not allowed for the type of table space. Table space name: "USERSPACE1". Table space type: "AUTOMATIC STORAGE". Incompatible clause: "RESIZE".. SQLCODE=-20318, SQLSTATE=42858, DRIVER=4.15.82
```

Look like the `automatic storage` restrict me to extends the size. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think you need to resize an automatic storage tablespace? The whole idea of automatic storage is that you _don't_ need to do that.

Comment: I am plan to add in another column for this table. But I hit the `tablespace` problem when I want to add.

Comment: If you are trying to change the tablespace page size (which is different from _resizing_) -- that is not possible. You will need to create a new tablespace and move your table there.